# Getting all users email by id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send email to users who have activate option in second table but not sure how to.

## Logic

1. Get all user id's from `mailings` table
2. check if their `latest_blog` column is set to `on`
3. send email to those users

## Code

```
$latest_blog = Mailing::where('latest_blog', 'on')->pluck('user_id');
$users = User::whereIn('id', [$latest_blog])->get();
foreach($users as $user){
  Mail::to($user->email)->send(new BlogUpdates($user, $post));
}
```

`dd($latest_blog);` returns

```
Collection {#1705 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => 41
    1 => 51
    2 => 42
    3 => 60
    4 => 61
  ]
}
```

`dd($users);` returns only 1 user while all users have column `latest_blog` set to `on`. so basically it supposed to return 5 users and not 1.

```
Collection {#1758 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => User {#1756 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Any idea?

## Update

`Mailing model`

```
protected $fillable = [
  'user_id', 'interests', 'security', 'latest_projects', 'latest_blog'
];

public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`User model`

```
protected $fillable = [
  'name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'points', 'google2fa_secret'
];

public function mails()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Mailing::class);
}
```

`Mailing Schema`

```
Schema::create('mailings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->unique();
            $table->string('interests')->default('on');
            $table->string('security')->default('on');
            $table->string('latest_projects')->default('on');
            $table->string('latest_blog')->default('on');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('mailings', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Please show us table structure and sample data for both tables.  My general advice: Get the raw MySQL query working completely, then worry about how to code it up in Laravel.

Comment: Where did you place `dd($users)` ? if you have dumped inside loop then it will always dispaly only user.

Comment: @SagarGautam no it was above foreach under `$users`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll update my question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you are doing is correct but you are adding extra array in `whereIn` clause. Since, pluck already returns a array, there is no need to add [ ] again in `whereIn` clause so,

your code should be

```
$latest_blog = Mailing::where('latest_blog', 'on')->pluck('user_id');
$users = User::whereIn('id', $latest_blog)->get();
foreach($users as $user){
   Mail::to($user->email)->send(new BlogUpdates($user, $post));
}
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: @mafortis I think you are getting only first user in your code before, and now you will get correct ones. Any way congrats.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$latest_blog = Mailing::where('latest_blog', 'on')->get()->pluck('user_id');
// dd($latest_blog);
$users = User::whereIn('id', $latest_blog->toArray())->get();
foreach($users as $user){
  Mail::to($user->email)->send(new BlogUpdates($user, $post));
}
```

Comment: pluck already returns array so why we need `->toArray()` function in a array ?

Comment: @SagarGautam "While most Eloquent collection methods return a new instance of an Eloquent collection, the pluck, keys, zip, collapse, flatten and flip methods return a base collection instance. Likewise, if a map operation returns a collection that does not contain any Eloquent models, it will be automatically cast to a base collection." https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections

Comment: @MostafaHadian thats good but my point is when we use pluck it will return associated or indexed array which is already acceptable for eloquent `whereIn` clause. So, I don't think we need extra `toArray`.